# Create new object knowing reflected type

Tags: reflection, go

In function, one of arguments I'm passing

```
reflect.TypeOf(Person)
```

where person is `struct` with few strings. If another function which accepts this argument, I want to instantiate this empty struct knowing its reflected type.

I have tried following

```
ins := reflect.New(typ)  //typ is name or passed reflect.TypeOf(Person)
```

But this returns me `nil`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that by using `reflect.New()`, you are making a pointer to a zero value of your struct, like with `new()`. If you just want the struct directly, rather than a pointer to it, you should use `reflect.Zero()` to get the zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell what you're doing wrong we should see more of your code. But this is a simple example how to do what you want:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    p := Person{}

    p2 := create(reflect.TypeOf(p))

    p3 := p2.(*Person)
    p3.Name = "Bob"
    p3.Age = 20
    fmt.Printf("%+v", p3)
}

func create(t reflect.Type) interface{} {
    p := reflect.New(t)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", p)

    pi := p.Interface()
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", pi)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pi)

    return pi
}
```

Output ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HmAdUob0SV)):

```
<*main.Person Value>
*main.Person
&{Name: Age:0}
&{Name:Bob Age:20}
```

[`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) returns a value of [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). The returned `Value` represents a pointer to a new zero value for the specified type.

You can use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) to extract the pointer.

`Value.Interface()` returns a value of type `interface{}`. Obviously it can't return any concrete type, just the general empty interface. The empty interface is not a `struct`, so you can't refer to any field. But it may (and in your case it does) hold a value of `*Person`. You can use [Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain a value of type `*Person`.

Comment: After i added used p.Interface(), i have faced this issue
person.Name undefined (type interface {} has no field or method Name). What did i miss this time?

Comment: @Avdept See my edited answer. `Value.Interface()` returns an `interface{}`, an empty interface which is not a `struct` so you can't refer to any fields. You have to use Type assertion to obtain a value of type `*Person`.

Comment: Thank you @icza. The only problem - i don't know in advance what exactly type will i receive in my argument, since there are some structs, that may inherit from my Person{}. Is there any way to convert, knowing only reflection.TypeOf?

Comment: @Avdept You may do a `switch` based on the type, and try to assert the dynamic type it holds. Type assertion also has a comma-ok idiom telling if type assertion failed or succeeded.

Comment: @Alessio You want the pointed value instead? In `main()` function `p3` is a pointer, you can do this: `var notPointer = *p3` - and `notPointer` will be of type `Person`.